# How can I reverse a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
Main_Input = int(input())

print("_________________")
while Main_Input > 0:
    c1 = Main_Input % 2
    Main_Input = Main_Input // 2
    print(c1)
```

I want to convert all the output value of "c1" variable into a whole number and reverse it. How can I do this?(This code is for converting natural numbers to binary numbers)

I searched the internet but could not find anything. I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: Hint: Convert to a string, reverse the characters.

Comment: Thak you. I find it.(●'◡'●)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *This code is for converting natural numbers to binary numbers*

The easiest way would be

```
Main_Input = int(input())

bin(Main_Input)[2:]
```

If you want to reverse it:

```
bin(Main_Input)[2:][::-1]
```

with while loop:

```
Main_Input = int(input())
remainder = 0
x = ""
n = Main_Input 

while n > 0:  
    remainder = (n%2)
    x = str(remainder) + x
    n = n//2

print(x, "is the binary of", Main_Input)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
MainInput=int(input())print("_________________")while Main_Input > 0rev = Main_Input % 2 Main_Input=Main_Input // 2print(rev)
```

Comment: format your answer in better way..!